# How can I add space between bracket and single quotation mark in java?

Tags: java, string

I am trying to convert the following string

```sql
Insert into table01 values('abcd01','abcd02','abcd03')
```

to

```sql
Insert into table01 values( 'abcd01', 'abcd02', 'abcd03' )
```

**My code:**

```
package layout;
public class String02 {
    public String Replace01(String testString) {
        String string01 = "";
        string01 = testString.replaceAll("\\('", "\\(  ");
        string01 = testString.replaceAll("\\)", "  \\)");
        string01 = testString.replaceAll(",", ", ");
        return string01;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String02 app = new String02();
        String testString = "Insert into table01 values('abcd01','abcd02','abcd03')";
        String s1 = app.Replace01(testString);
        System.out.println(s1);
    }
}
```

Comment: `replaceAll("\\('", "\\(  ")` should be `replaceAll("\\(", "\\(  ")` otherwise you're losing the single quote before the first value. BTW: This isn't a problem that should be solved with a regular expression, consider what happens with - for example - `Insert into table01 values('abcd(01)','abcd02','abcd03')`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
    string01 = testString.replaceAll("\\('", "\\(  ");
    string01 = testString.replaceAll("\\)", "  \\)");
    string01 = testString.replaceAll(",", ", ");
```

Strings are immutable. You can't keep operating on the original string as a new string is returned from each replaceAll() statement.

The code should be:

```
    string01 = testString.replaceAll("\\('", "\\(  '");
    string01 = string01.replaceAll("\\)", "  \\)");
    string01 = string01.replaceAll(",", ", ");
```

Also, your first replaceAll(...) statement was incorrect, since you missed the `'` in the replacement string.

Answer (score 3):

The error was mainly that you did not use `string01` for the second and third replacement,
but the original `testString`. (`replace(All/First)` will not change the string itself, but yield a new string).
So the first and second replacements are lost.

Then you do not need regular expression replaces. You can write all like:

```
    string01 = testString.replace("('", "( '")
                         .replace(")", " )")
                         .replace("','", "', '");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the regex `('(?=\\))|\\,|\\()` and capture group reference `$1` with `replaceAll()` method :

```
String testString = "Insert into table01 values('abcd01','abcd02','abcd03')";
String string01 = testString.replaceAll("('(?=\\))|\\,|\\()", "$1 ");
System.out.println(string01);
```

- `(...)` : capture group
- `$1` : capture group reference
- `|` : OR operator
- `(?=...)` : positive lookahead to capture `'` before `)`

Output:

```
Insert into table01 values( 'abcd01', 'abcd02', 'abcd03' )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are having trouble with regular expressions, do consider going back to the basics.

```java
public class String02 {
    public String Replace01(String testString) {
        String string01 = "";
        char ch;
        for(int i=0; i<testString.length(); i++){
            ch = testString.charAt(i);
            if(ch=='(' || ch==','){
                if((i+1)<testString.length() && testString.charAt(i+1)!=' '){
                    string01 += ch + " ";
                    continue;
                }
            }else if (ch==')'){
                if((i-1)>=0 && testString.charAt(i-1)!=' '){
                    string01 += " " + ch;
                    continue;
                }
            }
            string01 += ch;
        }
        return string01;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String02 app = new String02();
        String testString = "Insert into table01 values('abcd01','abcd02','abcd03')";
        String s1 = app.Replace01(testString);
        System.out.println(s1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also use lookarounds to find the specific *positions*, and in the replacement use a single space.

```
(?<=\(|',)(?=')|(?<=')(?=\))
```

See the positions in this [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SNDJyR/1) or a [Java demo](https://ideone.com/ccHy44).

- `(?<=\(|',)(?=')` Positive lookbehind assertion, if at the left is either `(` or `',` and at the right is `'`
- `|` Or
- `(?<=')(?=\))` Positive lookbehind assertions, if at the left is `'` and at the right is `)`

Example

```
String s = "Insert into table01 values('abcd01','abcd02','abcd03')";
String result = s.replaceAll("(?<=\\(|',)(?=')|(?<=')(?=\\))", " ");
System.out.println(result);
```

Output

```
Insert into table01 values( 'abcd01', 'abcd02', 'abcd03' )
```